# Autorelease then retain for setters

Tags: objective-c, properties, autorelease

According to the [Google Objective-C Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml?showone=Autorelease_Then_Retain#Autorelease_Then_Retain), we should autorelease then retain as so:

```
- (void)setFoo:(GMFoo *)aFoo {
  [foo_ autorelease];  // Won't dealloc if |foo_| == |aFoo|
  foo_ = [aFoo retain];
}
```

In this case, foo_ will not be deallocated if being set to the same instance, making for a more defensive setter.

My question is, is this how @property & @synthesize work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

release due to an autorelease isn't called until the end of the current runloop so foo_ wont dealloc because retain is called first followed by release at the end of the current runloop. However, this isn't how the code generated in @synthesize works. It works more like

```
- (void)setFoo:(GMFoo *)aFoo {
   if (aFoo != foo_) {
      [aFoo retain];
      [foo_ release];
      foo_ = aFoo;
   } 
}
```

This method saves cpu cycles when no change is necessary and takes out the small overhead of using the autorelease pool.

Comment: If that's the case, then isn't Google's recommendation less optimal?

Comment: Yes. It looks more appealing, but it is less optimal.

Comment: If you don't use [foo_ autorelease] you may encounter race conditions if the object is nonatomic and it is accessed from another thread. By using [foo_ autorelease] we usually only pay a small performance hit for peace of mind! Hence Google's recommendation.

Comment: Can't you simplify the body of the `if` statement by simply doing `[foo_ release]; foo_ = [aFoo retain];`?